# jQuery - mousedown - do thing after time and repeat until mouseup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code. It is animating car icon on google maps api.

```
$("#p_inc").mousedown(function () {
    if(mouseDownAnim) clearInterval(mouseDownAnim);
     moveCar();
    mouseDownInc = true;
    this.timer = setTimeout(function(){
        if(mouseDownInc){
            mouseDownAnim = setInterval(function () {
                moveCar();
            }, 150);
        }
        else{
            if(mouseDownAnim) clearInterval(mouseDownAnim);
        }
    },200);
})

$("#p_dec").mousedown(function () {
    backCar();
    if(mouseDownAnim) clearInterval(mouseDownAnim);
    mouseDownDec = true;
    this.timer = setTimeout(function(){
        if(mouseDownDec){
            mouseDownAnim = setInterval(function () {
                backCar();
            }, 150);
        }
        else{
            if(mouseDownAnim) clearInterval(mouseDownAnim);
        }
    },200);
});

$(document).on('mouseup',function(){
    mouseDownInc = false;
    mouseDownDec = false;
    clearInterval(mouseDownAnim);
});
```

What i expect? When i click on button then moveCar() should trigger once, but when i click and hold button - moveCar() should trigger once , wait a 200ms and after that should repeat moveCar() every 150ms until i do mouseup.  It is working but sometimes setInterval stack and i cant stop it. Where is bug?

**JSFIDDLE**: https://jsfiddle.net/2hbkrs6m/

Comment: OK i found solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968023/delay-musedown-interval-start-jquery-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

working code

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
<title>- jsFiddle demo</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/css/result-light.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css"></style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
 var mouseDownInc = false;
 var mouseDownDec = false;
 var mouseDownAnim = null;

$("#p_inc").mousedown(function (event) {
    if(mouseDownAnim) clearInterval(mouseDownAnim);
    moveCar();
    mouseDownInc = true;
 if(mouseDownInc){
  mouseDownAnim = setInterval(function () {
   moveCar();
  }, 150);
 }
});

$("#p_dec").mousedown(function (event) {
    if(mouseDownAnim) clearInterval(mouseDownAnim);
    backCar();
    mouseDownDec = true;
 if(mouseDownDec){
  mouseDownAnim = setInterval(function () {
   backCar();
  }, 150);
 }
});

$(document).on('mouseup',function(){
    mouseDownInc = false;
    mouseDownDec = false;
    clearInterval(mouseDownAnim);
});

function moveCar(){console.log("movecar")
}
function backCar(){console.log("backcar")
}
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="p_inc">Move</button>
<button id="p_dec">Back</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If u do fast double click and hold mousedown then i cant stop interval ;/